# Dynamically build url to documentset homepage

Tags: 2013, development, csom, sharepoint-on-prem

I have some methods using CSOM that are being called form an external program. In one of these methods I check if a document set exists on a certain location, and if it does I want to return the url to the document set homepage for that document set.

I've manage to get the url down to this structure to get a working url:

```
http://sharepoint/sitename/library/forms/DocumentSetContentTypeName/docsethomepage.aspx?RootFolder=/sitename/library/documentsetname
```

With querying several properties of the web etc, I could dynamically get the contenttypename, url etc.

I'm just wondering if there's no easier path to get an url to the document set.

Also I would a suggestion to get rid of the DocumentSetName in the url to open the page. If it would work with only providing an id, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

**Best way** to build URL for document set homepage dynamically use this built-in page:

```
http://<websiteurl>/_layouts/15/DocSetHome.aspx?id=<server relative url of document set>
```

This SharePoint page will redirect you to correct document set homepage. You can get url of the document set using `FileRef` indexed property of `SP.ListItem` object.

Example, `http://site/web/_layouts/15/DocSetHome.aspx?id=/site/web/library/docset1`

**Alternatively**, you could can treat document set as folder and build link to *folder url*, like `http://site/web/library/docset1` of the document set. Generally SharePoint will handle this and redirect you to document set home page instead of default view. Although I have noticed that this way is not very reliable if you have deeper folder structure in your document library.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I've got so far:

```
Web web = context.Web;
context.Load(web, w => w.Url);

List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
context.Load(list, l => l.Id);

var items = list.GetItems(createGetDocSetQuery(query));
context.Load(items, folders => folders.Include(
    folder => folder["ID"],
    folder => folder["ServerUrl"],
    folder => folder["FileRef"]
    ));
context.ExecuteQuery();
count = items.Count();
if(count == 1)
{
    url = web.Url + "/documenten/Forms/ContentTypeName/docsethomepage.aspx?ID=" + items[0]["ID"];
    url += "&RootFolder=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(items[0]["FileRef"].ToString());
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way.